# How can I get a list of all site urls, site titles, and their site owners through powershell?

Tags: powershell

I've been able to get the following:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | 
Get-SPWeb -Limit All | 
where { $_.HasUniquePerm -and $_.AssociatedOwnerGroup -ne $null } | 
foreach { 
$url = $_.Url; $_ } | 
Select -ExpandProperty AssociatedOwnerGroup | 
Select -ExpandProperty Users | 
Select {$url}, UserLogin, DisplayName | Export-csv c:\test.csv -notypeinformation
```

This gives me the site url, site owner's logins and display names.  However, I can't figure out how to also get the site title.  I seem restricted to either getting the title or the url of a site.  How can I pull back both through this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this script:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | 
Get-SPWeb -Limit All | 
where { $_.HasUniquePerm -and $_.AssociatedOwnerGroup -ne $null } | 
foreach { 
$url = $_.Url; $title = $_.Title; $_ } | 
Select -ExpandProperty AssociatedOwnerGroup | 
Select -ExpandProperty Users | 
Select {$url}, {$title}, UserLogin, DisplayName | Export-csv c:\test.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Ha! I could have sworn that I'd tried this.  Thanks @Ransher